# An application of Jensen's Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Given that $\{\phi_n\}$ is a sequence of non-negative numbers whose sum is $1$ and $\{\psi_n\}$ is a sequence of positive numbers, how can I show that 
$$ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}~\psi_n^{\phi_n}~\leq~\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}~\phi_n\psi_n~? $$

Thanks.

PS: I'm not too sure about the title. Perhaps, someone could give it a better title?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the proof from [page 92](http://books.google.com/books?id=7GDyRMrlgDsC&pg=PA92) of 
[The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Publications/Books/CSMC/CSMC_index.html) by J. Michael Steele.

Since the exponential function is convex, Jensen's inequality gives
$$\exp\left(\sum_n \phi_n y_n\right)\leq \sum_n \phi_n e^{y_n}.$$

Letting $\psi_n=e^{y_n}$ above we get
$$\prod_{n}\ \psi_n^{\phi_n} \leq \sum_n \phi_n \psi_n.$$

Comment: Aaaah... Glad to see someone referring to this wonderful book. +1.

Comment: @Didier I agree. It is one of my favorites!

Comment: (+1) To both you and Didier. The Steele book is another (somewhat) "hidden" gem that we share an affection for. :)

Answer (score 5):

Your inequality
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}~\psi_n^{\phi_n}~\leq~\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}~\phi_n\psi_n$$
is equivalent to
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\phi_n} \ln \psi_n \leq \ln \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \phi_n\psi_n\right).$$

This can be obtained from the integral form of [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_and_probabilistic_form): The following is true for any concave function
$$\varphi\left(\int_\Omega g\, d\mu\right) \ge \int_\Omega \varphi \circ g\, d\mu. $$
(I have copied it from wikipedia, just changed convex to concave and change the inequality sign.)

You obtain the above inequality for:

- concave function $\varphi(x)=\ln(x)$
- measure space $\Omega=\mathbb N$ with the measure determined by $\mu(\{n\})=\phi_n$
- function $g:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ given by $g(n)=\psi_n$.

The measure $\mu$ is sometimes called [discrete measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_measure).

Or, equivalently, you can look at $\psi_n$'s as probabilities and then use the probabilistic form of Jensen's inequality. (Comparing the mean value of logarithm and logarithm of the mean value.)

---

If you prefer, you might also use the finite version of Jensen's inequality:
$$\varphi\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^k a_i x_i}{\sum_{j=1}^k a_j}\right) \ge \frac{\sum_{i=1}^k a_i \varphi (x_i)}{\sum_{j=1}^k a_j}$$
(again - the above formula is copied from wikipedia and I changed the sign) and then take the limit.

Alternatively, you can use the finite version to prove
$$\prod_{n=1}^{N} \psi_n^{\phi_n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N} \phi_n\psi_n \qquad (*)$$
for arbitrary finite sequence $(\phi_n)$ fulfilling $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \phi_n=1$, use this for sequence and then use this to derive the same thing for your original -- infinite -- sequence, by taking the inequality (*) for $\phi_1,\dots,\phi_N,1-\sum_{i=1}^N \phi_i$ and $\psi_1,\dots,\psi_n,0$. (In this way the limits are slightly less complicated and you do not have the sum $\sum_{j=1}^k \phi_j$ in denominator.)

---

BTW It's worth mentioning that this is a generalization of [AM-GM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_inequality#Generalizations).

Answer (score 3):

We can apply Jensen inequality for a finite sums, i.e. $\sum_{k=1}^N\alpha_kf(x_k)\leq f\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_kx_k\right)$ if $\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k=1$. To see that, fix $n\in\mathbb N$ and put $c_k:=\frac{a_k}{\sum_{j=1}^na_j}$. Then by concavity of $x\mapsto \ln x$:
\begin{align}
\ln\prod_{k=1}^nb_k^{a_k}&=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\ln b_k\\
&=\left(\sum_{j=1}^na_j\right)\sum_{k=1}^nc_k\ln b_k\\
&\leq \left(\sum_{j=1}^na_j\right)\ln\left(\sum_{k=1}^nc_k b_k\right)
\\
&=\left(\sum_{j=1}^na_j\right)\left(\ln\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_k b_k\right)-\ln\left(\sum_{j=1}^na_j\right)\right)\\
&\leq\ln\left(\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}a_k b_k\right)-\ln\left(\sum_{j=1}^na_j\right), 
\end{align}
and since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^na_j=1$ we get the result, taking the $\limsup$.